# /dev/mapper/RHELCSB-Home marked as full when it is not after verification

Tags: linux, memory

I was trying to copy a 1.5GiB file from a location to another and was warned that my disk space is full, so I proceeded to a verification using `df -h`, which gave the following output:

```
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                   16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      16G  114M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      16G  2.0M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs                      16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/RHELCSB-Root   50G   11G   40G  21% /
/dev/nvme0n1p2            3.0G  436M  2.6G  15% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1            200M   17M  184M   9% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/RHELCSB-Home  100G  100G  438M 100% /home
tmpfs                     3.1G   88K  3.1G   1% /run/user/4204967
```

where `/dev/mapper/RHELCSB-Home` seemed to cause the issue. But when running `sudo du -xsh /dev/mapper/RHELCSB-Home`, I got the following result:

```
0   /dev/mapper/RHELCSB-Home
```

and same thing for `/dev/` and `/dev/mapper/`. After researching this issue, I figured out that this might have been caused by undeleted log files in `/var/log/`, but the total size of files there is far from approaching the 100GiB. What could cause my disk space to be full?

Additional context: I was running a local postgresql database when this happened, but I can't see how this can relate to my issue as postgres log files are not taking that much space either.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved by deleting podman container volumes in `~/.local/share/containers/`